# How to update existing data and increase a certain value in phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to seed some random data into my Database, I simplified the code here:

```
alias MyApp.Repo
alias MyApp.Datas.Data

for x <- 0..1000 do
  n = random_name()         #gives back 1 of 20 different names ("Bob", "Rick", "Sean", ...)
  v = Enum.random(1..100)
  %Data{name: n, value: v} |> Repo.insert!()
end
```

But now i want to change the Repo.insert() so, that when a Name was already inserted, for example

```
%{id: 14, name: "Rick", value: 57, timestamps....})
```

the value of the existing "Rick" with the id 14 increases by the new randomly generated value v, Instead of just inserting another "Rick" with a another value v.

Could I do something with Repo.insert_or_update?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function, and while one might deal with [`Ecto.Query.select/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#select/3) followed by subsequent [`Ecto.Query.update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#update/3) or [`Ecto.Repo.insert/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:insert/2), or even introduce a unique key, call `insert!/2` and rescue the exception raised on duplicates, I personally would go with a more reasonable approach: keep the state on the client side.

```rb
0..1000
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn i, acc ->
  n = random_name()
  v = Enum.random(1..100)

  Map.update(acc, n, v, & &1+v)
end)
|> Enum.each(&Repo.insert!(%Data{name: &1, value: &2}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he means the insert_or_update function that is defined in the Ecto.Repo Behavior.  [insert_or_update](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_or_update/2)

This behavior is implemented by a "Repo" module, by default, when running mix phx.new

I believe something like this will work. (Iterations omitted)

```
defmodule User do
use Ecto.Schema 
  schema "users" do
    field :id, :string, primary_key: true
    field :name,    :string, primary_key: true
    field :value,   :integer
  end

  def changeset(record, params \\ %{}) do
    record
    |> cast(params, [:value)
    |> validate_required([:value])
  end

end

defmodule SomeMod do
def test_func() do
  a_name = get_random_name()
  user_ecto_struct = 
    Repo.get_by(User, name: a_name)
    |> case do
     nil -> %User{name: a_name...} // create a new user
     user -> user
  
  new_value = old_user_ecto_struct.value + random_value()
  Repo.insert_or_update(user_ecto_struct, %{value: new_value})

end
end
```

insert_or_update takes in the old state to prevent race conditions.
I.e. it checks that the data we are updating hasn't been changed since we read it